# downloading an excel file from the web in python

Tags: python, download

I have the following web address:

```
dls = "http://www.muellerindustries.com/uploads/pdf/UW SPD0114.xls"
```

I tried to download the file:

```
urllib2.urlopen(dls, "test.xls")
```

This made a file called "test.xls" but this is clearly an html file.  If I opened the html file in firefox it opened an excel file, but if I opened the file in excel it was definitely not the excel file I was looking for.

If I have a web address like the one above, how do I make python download the excel file as an excel file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I download a zip file in python using urllib2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028697/how-do-i-download-a-zip-file-in-python-using-urllib2)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would save the excel file in the same folder that the script was ran from.

```
import urllib
dls = "http://www.muellerindustries.com/uploads/pdf/UW SPD0114.xls"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(dls, "test.xls")  # For Python 3
# urllib.urlretrieve(dls, "test.xls")  # For Python 2
```

Comment: I used your code and got error . I solved the problem by changing to `urllib.request.urlretrieve(dls, "test.xls")`

Answer (score 42):

I suggest using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html):

```
import requests
dls = "http://www.muellerindustries.com/uploads/pdf/UW SPD0114.xls"
resp = requests.get(dls)

output = open('test.xls', 'wb')
output.write(resp.content)
output.close()
```

To get requests installed:

```
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 20):

To add on to Fedalto's requests suggestion (+1), but make it more Pythonic with a context manager:

```
import requests
dls = "http://www.muellerindustries.com/uploads/pdf/UW SPD0114.xls"
resp = requests.get(dls)
with open('test.xls', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(resp.content)
```

Answer (score 5):

Two issues, one with the code (below), the other that the URL is bad. A (modern) web browser will automatically correct "http://www.muellerindustries.com/uploads/pdf/UW SPD0114.xls" to "http://www.muellerindustries.com/uploads/pdf/UW%20SPD0114.xls" but Python doesn't.

This code works for me on python 3.x

```
import urllib
outfilename = "test.xls"
url_of_file = "http://www.muellerindustries.com/uploads/pdf/UW%20SPD0114.xls"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_of_file, outfilename)
```

Which gets me the file.