# How do I download the artifacts from a jenkins build through python

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How do I download the artifacts from a Jenkins build to my local machine using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you want to download via http.

You might want to use GNU wget for example, but if you really want to use Python - check out [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python). Urllib2 provides an easy way to handle http requests.

This is providing that you will not need to perform any additional actions to get to the file (authentication etc.).

Comment: I am getting below Error:   `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/url_doenlaod.py", line 3, in <module>
   
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden             `

Comment: Go to http://<your_jenkins>/user/<your_username>/configure and add credentials 'not bound to a domain'.

After that you can use urllib2 password manager:

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, username, password)
urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)))

Haven't tested if this will work myself, but it is worth a try.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407126/python-urllib2-basic-auth-problem for a reference

Comment: Actually i have a Folder in jenkins url that i need to Download it through urllib2.But when i am Downloading it is Downloading as a single file but i want the Directory to be Downloaded. how can I achieve that one..

Comment: The above comment  is a new requirement

Comment: ${JENKINS_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/*zip*/archive.zip will return zipped artifacts for a build. You can then use any of python's libraries that can unzip the archive. Use ${BUILD_NUMBER} i you want something else than 'lastSuccessfulBuild'

Comment: what is artifact in the above mentioned.?

Comment: I used below one .`username = "username"
password = "password"
url = 'http://jenkins/view/mine/job/mine_Linux/ws/release/build_35-31683/*zip*/archive.zip'

print("calling %s with %s:%s\n" % (url, username, password))
import urllib2, base64
import zipfile
request = urllib2.Request(url)
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
data=result.read()
print result,data
output=open('mine_driver.zip','wb')
output.write(result.read())
output.close()`

Comment: It is not downloading.An Empty Compressed file is created.

Comment: http://jenkins/view/mine/job/mine_Linux/ws/release/build_35-31683/*zip*/archive‌​.zip

Is not the correct link. Why do you enter workspace? I've already provided the correct link: 


 
    ${JENKINS_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/artifact/*zip*/archive.zip (downloads all build archived artifacts in zip format)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028697/how-do-i-download-a-zip-file-in-python-using-urllib2

Has an example that can be copy - pasted and run. Worked for me a minute ago.

Comment: ok.Thanks got the solution....  I used workspace the folder i want to download is under workspace/release Folder...

Comment: You're welcome :) . May I ask what was the issue with file download from workspace? To be honest, I don't think it's a good idea to use workspace to download files from, as you won't be able to access files from previous builds and workspace may be owrwritten / cleaned up by a new instance of a build. Also, please accept the answer if it did answered your question :) Cheers