# How to download a zip file from a site (python)

Tags: python, file, download, zip

There is a site with logs and each log is in zip (for space saving).
How can I download it from the site?

( urllib / urllib2 )(?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`urllib.urlretrieve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) this way:

```
urlretrieve(your_url, your_zip_path)
```

Comment: As said in doc, `Deprecated since version 2.6: The urlopen() function has been removed in Python 3 in favor of urllib2.urlopen().` this answer needs some updates from Python3's perspective.

Answer (score 4):

You have to consider something like:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.website.com/log.zip')
zipcontent= response.read()
```

and now you write the file to disk :)

```
with open("log.zip", 'w') as f:
    f.write(zipcontent)
```

You can also check:
[Python and urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289768/python-and-urllib)

[download a zip file to a local drive and extract all files to a destination folder using python 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774434/download-a-zip-file-to-a-local-drive-and-extract-all-files-to-a-destination-fold)