# Download ZIP file from the web (Python)

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to download a ZIP file using from [this website](http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip). I have looked at other [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760992/how-to-download-a-zip-file-from-a-site-python), tried using the `requests` and `urllib` but I get the same error:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop. The last 30x error message was: Found
```

**Any ideas on how to open the file straight from the web?**

Here is some sample code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
response = urlopen('http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip')
```

Comment: that's because the above url will send you in a redirect loop

Comment: So I can't open the zip file straight from the web?

Answer (score 1):

The linked url will redirect indefinitely, that's why you get the 302 error.

You can examine this yourself [over here](http://redirectdetective.com/). As you can see the linked url immediately redirects to itself creating a single-url loop.

Comment: So I can't open the zip file straight from the web?

Comment: Well, not from that url at least.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me using the Requests library

```
import requests

url = 'http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip'

response = requests.get(url)

# Unzip it into a local directory if you want
import zipfile, io

zip = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))
zip.extractall("/path/to/your/directory")
```

Note that sometimes trying to access web pages programmatically leads to 302 responses because they only want you to access the page via a web browser.
If you need to fake this (don't be abusive), just set the 'User-Agent' header to be like a browser. Here's an example of making a request look like it's coming from a Chrome browser.

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

There are several libraries (e.g. https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/) to help with this for more extensive scraping projects.